# Path for file outside document root windows server

Tags: php, include, windows-server-2003

I want to include a file one level up from document root. I am on a windows server 2003.

I have tried both of the apporaches without success, any suggestions?

```
include("../inc/myfile.php");
inlcude("C:\Inetpub\vhosts\mysite.com\inc\myfile.php");
```

Answer (score 1):

The latter would require backslashes to be escaped, so it would read:

```
include("C:\\Inetpub\\vhosts\\mysite.com\\inc\\myfile.php");
```

Being more specific about what isn't working would be helpful.  Are you getting an error message?  How is your PHP server configured?  Are there any safe mode restrictions in place?

Comment: you're probably right, but I'd suggest using addslashes() rather than escaping each of the slashes.

Comment: I'm not sure that's gonna work quite right.  \I and \v are going to become escape sequences in the string parser, long before addslashes gets a hold of them.  Single-quoting the string could work.

Comment: Best to use forward slashes for all your paths, anyways. PHP will auto-translate for you on Windows.